# Otimização inserts hibernate quando há relacionamento @ManyToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, otimização, relacionamento

Imagine os relacionamentos:

> User has many Permissions
>
> Permission has many Users

Podemos criar um relacionamento de `N para N` da seguinte forma:

**User.class**

```
public class User {
  /*Many attributes here*/
  private List permissions;
  
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy =         "users")
  public List getPermissions() {
    return permissions;
  }
  public void setPermissions(List permissions){
    this.permissions = permissions;
  }
}
```

**Permission.class**

```
public class Permission{
  /*Many attributes here..*/
  private List users;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
  }

  public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
  }
}
```

Assim pode-se afirmar um relacionamento de `N pra N` sendo que o *owner* é a classe `Permission`.

Quando quero dizer que o usuário **1** tem as permissões **3** e **5**, por exemplo, faço algo assim:

```
User u = (User)session.get(User.class,  1);

List permissions = new ArrayList<>();
permissions.add(new Permission(3));
permissions.add(new Permission(5));

for(Object permission : permissions){
  Permission p = 
        (Permission) session.get(Permission.class, ((Permission)permission).getId());
  p.getUsers().add(u);
}

session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Tudo funcionando corretamente.

No entanto, quando visualizo os *logs*, vejo que o *hibernate* está primeiramente excluindo todos os registros da tabela associativa `permission_user` relacionados aquela permissão, depois adicionando tudo novamente. (Uma vez que nós temos acesso a todos os usuários anteriormente associados quando chamamos `p.getUsers(); //pega todos os usuários já associados`)

Vamos supor que a permissao **3** já tenha o usuário **100** e o usuário **101** associados a ela, e então quero associar agora o usuário **1**.
Nos *logs*, o *hibernate* ta executando mais ou menos isso...

```
delete from permission_user where id_permission = ? //deve ser id 3
insert into permission_user (id_permission, id_user) values (?, ?) //deve ser 3 e 100 respectivamente
insert into permission_user (id_permission, id_user) values (?, ?) //deve ser 3 e 101 respectivamente
insert into permission_user (id_permission, id_user) values (?, ?) //deve ser 3 e 1 respectivamente
```

A questão é, como estou associando um usuário novo, a minha expectativa é que o *hibernate* possa executar o `insert` apenas uma vez (Já que o usuário **100** e **101** já estão presentes na tabela associativa).
E isso ocorre para cada permissão. Logo, se eu disser que o usuário **1** terá as permissões, **3**, **5**, **10**, **11**, **12**, **13**, **15**, **16** e **19** e cada uma dessas permissões já tiver usuários associados a ela, cerca de 10 usuários por exemplo, o *hibernate* vai executar mais de 100 instruções para performar o que desejo. Isso é realmente muito problemático.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Não vejo necessidade de usar ManyToMany no seu problema. Um OneToMany resolveria sem complicações.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isso ocorre porque o Hibernate suporta uma característica adicional de uma coleção chamada `Bag`. Uma `Bag` é uma coleção que pode ter membros duplicados, porém não é ordenada. A melhor característica de uma `Bag` é que você pode obter o número de ocorrências de um objeto através da API usando o método `public int occurrences(Object o)`.
>
> Numa `List`, não há como fazer o mesmo sem iterar por todos os seus elementos.
>
> Então, quando uma `List` é mapeada sem uma coluna para a indexação, o Hibernate a trata como uma `Bag`. Em essência, uma `List`que possui uma coluna para a indexação é uma `Bag` indexada.
>
> Com o Hibernate tratando a `List` como uma `Bag`, ele acredita que pode haver elementos duplicados na join table. Além disso, ele sabe que os elementos na join table não estão ordenados. Então, não há como saber quais linhas devem ser deletadas do objeto em java.
>
> Então o Hibernate precisa continuar e re-inserir todas as linhas que ele sabe do java que não devem ser deletadas.
>
> Se você não necessita de objetos duplicados, você pode usar um `Set`. Um `Set` não precisa de uma coluna para a indexação e o Hibernate pode distinguir uma linha da sua tabela porque ele sabe que um `Set` não tem elementos duplicados.

[Fonte](http://assarconsulting.blogspot.com.br/2009/08/why-hibernate-does-delete-all-then-re.html)

Ou seja, ou você usa uma coluna para ordenar sua join table, ou usa um `Set` ao invés de uma `List`. No caso de manter a `List` ficaria assim:

Permission:

```
@Entity
public class Permission {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OrderColumn(name="order_id")
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<User> users;

    public Permission() {}

    public Permission(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

User:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "users")
    private List<Permission> permissions;

    public User() {}

    public User(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Permission> getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }

    public void setPermissions(List<Permission> permissions) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }
}
```

Teste:

```
public class Teste {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pt-stackoverflow");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    
        User u = em.find(User.class, 1);
     
        int permissions[] = {1, 2};
    
        for(int permission : permissions) {
            Permission p = em.find(Permission.class, permission);
            p.getUsers().add(u);
        }
    
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

Com a anotação:

> select user0_.id as id1_2_0_ from User user0_ where user0_.id=?
>
> select permission0_.id as id1_0_0_ from Permission permission0_ where permission0_.id=?
>
> select users0_.permissions_id as permissi1_1_0_, users0_.users_id as users_id2_1_0_, users0_.permissions_id_index_column as permissi3_0_, user1_.id as id1_2_1_ from Permission_User users0_ inner join User user1_ on users0_.users_id=user1_.id where users0_.permissions_id=?
>
> select permission0_.id as id1_0_0_ from Permission permission0_ where permission0_.id=?
>
> select users0_.permissions_id as permissi1_1_0_, users0_.users_id as users_id2_1_0_, users0_.permissions_id_index_column as permissi3_0_, user1_.id as id1_2_1_ from Permission_User users0_ inner join User user1_ on users0_.users_id=user1_.id where users0_.permissions_id=?
>
> insert into Permission_User (permissions_id, permissions_id_index_column, users_id) values (?, ?, ?)
>
> insert into Permission_User (permissions_id, permissions_id_index_column, users_id) values (?, ?, ?)

Nenhum `DELETE`!

Comment: +1 Perfeito. Não só pelo fato de ter postado a solução mas por ter também explicado linkando fontes.

Comment: engraçado que  tb estava tendo o mesmo problema (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/278354/por-que-o-hibernate-est%C3%A1-deletando-antes-do-saveorupdate), e estava usando um set e mesmo assim estava deletando. Fiz exatamente o oposto do que se fala aqui e usei um List.. e funcionou!