# Por que o hibernate está deletando antes do saveOrUpdate()?

Tags: java, hibernate

Eu tenho a uma relação m:n entre Coluna e Elemento. A entidade dona da relação é Coluna. porém quando eu estou salvando um mapa de Colunas,  acontece o seguinte cenário:

1) Na primeira iteração, o Hibernate:

1.1) salva o primeiro elemento Coluna

1.2) insere os dois elementos na tabela coluna_elemento

segue console:

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into coluna (COLUNA_ALIAS_OPERACAO, COLUNA_CLAUSULA, COLUNA_DATA_DOIS, COLUNA_DATA_UM, COLUNA_EXIBE_FILTRO, COLUNA_EXIBE_NO_RELATORIO, COLUNA_EXIBE_TOTALIZADOR, COLUNA_INDEX, COLUNA_LABEL, COLUNA_NOME, COLUNA_OPERACAO, COLUNA_OPERACAO_REFERNCIANDO_ALIAS, RELATORIO_ID, COLUNA_TEMPO_DOIS, COLUNA_TEMPO_UM, COLUNA_TIPO_CLAUSULA_TEXTO, COLUNA_TIPO_EXIBICAO, COLUNA_TIPO_FILTRO, COLUNA_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into coluna_elemento (COLUNA_ID, ELEMENTO_DOMINIO_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into coluna_elemento (COLUNA_ID, ELEMENTO_DOMINIO_ID) values (?, ?)
```

Neste momento a tabela coluna_elemento do meu banco está assim:

```
coluna_id | elemento_id
    988        860
    988        861
```

Até aqui está tudo ocorrendo conforme o esperado.

2) Na segunda iteração, o Hibernate:

2.1) salva o segundo elemento coluna

2.2) deleta da tabela coluna_elemento o elemento salvo anteriormente

2.3)insere os dois elementos na tabela coluna_elemento

Como mostra a saída do console a seguir:

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into coluna (COLUNA_ALIAS_OPERACAO, COLUNA_CLAUSULA, COLUNA_DATA_DOIS, COLUNA_DATA_UM, COLUNA_EXIBE_FILTRO, COLUNA_EXIBE_NO_RELATORIO, COLUNA_EXIBE_TOTALIZADOR, COLUNA_INDEX, COLUNA_LABEL, COLUNA_NOME, COLUNA_OPERACAO, COLUNA_OPERACAO_REFERNCIANDO_ALIAS, RELATORIO_ID, COLUNA_TEMPO_DOIS, COLUNA_TEMPO_UM, COLUNA_TIPO_CLAUSULA_TEXTO, COLUNA_TIPO_EXIBICAO, COLUNA_TIPO_FILTRO, COLUNA_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: delete from coluna_elemento where COLUNA_ID=?
Hibernate: insert into coluna_elemento (COLUNA_ID, ELEMENTO_DOMINIO_ID) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into coluna_elemento (COLUNA_ID, ELEMENTO_DOMINIO_ID) values (?, ?)
```

E então, a tabela coluna_elemento no banco está assim:

```
coluna_id  |  elemento_id
   989           860
   989           861
```

Quando o que eu esperava era o seguinte:

```
coluna_id | elemento_id
  988          860
  988          861
  989          860
  989          861
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

O código onde eu salvo o mapa de colunas é o seguinte:

```
private void salvaColunas() {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Coluna> entry : mapaColunas.entrySet()){
        Coluna coluna = entry.getValue();
        coluna.setRelatorio(relatorio);
        colunaDao.saveOrUpdate(coluna);
    }
}
```

A o método saveOrUpdate da minha classe Dao é o seguinte:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(T obj) {
    Session session;
    Transaction tx = null; 
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }catch (HibernateException ex) {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    }
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(obj);
        tx.commit();
      } catch (RuntimeException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
          if(session.isOpen()) {
              session.close();
          }
      }
 }
```

O mapeamento na classe coluna (já com os metodos equals e hashCode implementados) está assim :

```
@ManyToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, cascade= {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name="coluna_elemento",  joinColumns={
        @JoinColumn(name="COLUNA_ID", nullable=false, updatable=false )},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ELEMENTO_DOMINIO_ID", nullable=false, updatable = false)  })
private Set<ElementoDominio> elementosDoDominio;

public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((label == null) ? 0 : label.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((nome == null) ? 0 : nome.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Coluna other = (Coluna) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    if (label == null) {
        if (other.label != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!label.equals(other.label))
        return false;
    if (nome == null) {
        if (other.nome != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!nome.equals(other.nome))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

E minha classe Elemento (que também tem os métodos equals e hashCode implementados) está assim:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "elementosDoDominio")
private Set<Coluna> colunas;



@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((label == null) ? 0 : label.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    ElementoDominio other = (ElementoDominio) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    if (label == null) {
        if (other.label != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!label.equals(other.label))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Ambas as classes Coluna quanto Elemento tem mais atributos, inclusive o id que é gerado pelo Hibernate. Todos com getters e setters.

Alguém pod eme ajudar?
Obrigada

Comment: Faz o seguinte, coloca o updatable pra true no elementosDoDominio. Eu acho que ele deve estar tentando atualizar o objeto ao invés de inserir um novo. Só um palpite..

Comment: Tentei inserir as colunas num hashMap antes de salvar em cada interação e vi que ao invés do hash conter as duas colunas, ele está contendo uma só . O que me leva a crer que o meu método equals está retornando que as duas colunas são iguais.. mas não são!!!

Comment: Hmm, mas quando é no hash vc tem que implementar o hashCode, ele não usa o equals. Como ele está implementado?

Comment: gerei pelo eclipse

Comment: Coloca o método aqui.

Comment: pronto, coloquei!

Comment: Não dá pra ter ideia só olhando isso, sugiro que você debugue, coloque um breakpoint no método hashCode e veja se de fato ele está retornando true na segunda interação e por isso ele substitui o objeto anterior.

Comment: já fiz isso. Ele retorna false... portanto, não são iguais

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73594/discussion-between-giuliana-bezerra-and-tathiana-ianelli).

Comment: eu uso um set e não um list..não preciso do @OrderColumn

Answer (score 0):

bom, ao invés do set, eu usei um list e ele fez o que eu esperava (o oposto do que está sendo sugerido em [Otimização inserts hibernate quando há relacionamento @ManyToMany](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178154/otimiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-inserts-hibernate-quando-h%C3%A1-relacionamento-manytomany) ).

coloquei na classe Coluna:

```
private List<ElementoDominio> elementosDoDominio;// ao inves do Set
```

e na classe Elemento mudei para:

```
private List<Coluna> colunas; // tb mudei para list
```

nãos sei o motivo, mas funcionou... se alguém puder explicar, ganha um voto!